# connecting to a grails app database

Tags: grails, h2

I am a python developer by day, but I have some java experience as well (mostly with struts).  At work I was handed a grails app to install, which was ok, but the owners of the app didn't supply any credentials, and the app loads to a login page.

I unpacked the war, but I think the DB config has been packaged into a jar somewhere, because I can't seem to find any connection URL.  There's an h2 db file that's been created after I deployed the App, so I'm wondering:

how can I connect to the db like you normally would with SQLite or mysql client, browse tables, and create an admin user so I can login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with decompilation. You need not only a user and password, but at least a database [JDBC URL](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/help_db2.html). That may include DBMS name, host, port, database name - depending on Java driver specifics. Then connect as you would normally in Python or whatever, or with [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/).

But if the database is in H2/hsql (URL is like `jdbc:h2:mem:XXX`), you've got a problem: it is a Java in-process DBMS. In order to gain external access to it, you'll need to change the decompiled code, compile and pack it back with [some additions](http://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/share-an-h2-in-memory-database-among-several-jvms/). Hope it's not your case.

Another way in hsql/H2 case is to find and decompile database bootstrap code - as it's an in-process DB, it should be filled at every application startup, so there should be a code creating that superuser.

Comment: i did eventually decompile the code, and found the DB username and password.  then i examined the db file with an H2 DB GUI, only to find out that the public schema was empty.  i think the app has a url to set it up.  either way, there's a webex scheduled with the app owners tomorrow to guide us through the config

Comment: Good thing they are cooperating. BTW are you aware that the DB you exmined is NOT the DB the application is using? "In-process" means "in-memory" and "created anew each time the app is run", so a new instance was created in your H2 GUI. That's why I was talking about looking for bootstrap code in decompiled sources.

Answer (score 0):

In Grails, the DB configuration, including authentication settings, are declared in a file called `Datasource.groovy` which is then compiled into the WAR. You'll need the source code to find the username and password for the H2 DB.

Comment: I decompiled the DataSource.class to find the username and pass.  Then downloaded the h2 jar and ran:  **java -cp "h2-1.3.169.jar:$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" -Dh2.binAddress=0.0.0.0 org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpAllowOthers** but it's complaining about the driver.  any suggestions

Comment: silly me that i would think an installer would correctly set the env variable H2DRIVERS :) I am so glad I am python developer

Comment: Which driver did it not find? The H2 installer can't really know where the non-H2 JDBC drivers are...

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if Python can connect to a java datasource but it may be a solution.

An other solution may be to provide some REST webservice from Grails side to make it possible for the python program to access the database. This is the way I prefer and I often choose.

By the way, you have the configuration of the databases used by Grails in the conf directory (grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy) and you'll get the jdbc URL to the database which could be convert to a classical URL. For example : jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_app refers to the database my_app on localhost and default port for a mysql database.

Feel free to ask if you need more information.

Cheers

Comment: when i unpacked the war, there's was no conf directory in WEB-INF/grails-app, all that's there is views, that's why i'm thinking it's packaged into a jar somehow. there's a hibernate plugin directory, but no db config there either

Comment: just found this:  ./WEB-INF/classes/DataSource.class which confirm my suspicion