# Grails run-app error while connecting to a remote server database from a grails project over vpn

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I am working remotely for a firm based in India and I am connecting to the company network via VPN for daily work.

I am currently implementing a project in grails 2.2.4 which is on my local system / computer. The grails project in GGTS runs fine when connected to the local db on my machine.

But, when I am trying to connect to a database which is hosted in a server on my Company's network from my project's development environment, I am getting a lot of connection errors, all of it from MySQL.

I have configured my DataSource.groovy as below:

```
dataSource {
 pooled = true
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 username = <username>
 password = <password>
}
hibernate {
 cache.use_second_level_cache = true
 cache.use_query_cache=true
 cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
 cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
environments {
  development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://<remoteIP-on company network>:3306/<DB_Name>"
        properties{
            initialSize="50"
            maxActive="100"
            minIdle="50"
            maxIdle="75"
            maxWait="30000"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testOnReturn="true"
            poolPreparedStatements="true"
            maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
            connectionInitSqls="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
            logAbandoned="true"
        }
    }
  }
  test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://<remoteIP-on company network>:3306/<DB_Name>"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = <username>
        password = <password>
    }
  }
  production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/<JNDIName>"
        properties {
         maxActive = 50
            maxIdle = 25
            minIdle = 5
            initialSize = 5
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
            maxWait = 10000
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My BuildConfig.groovy has the following dependencies set:

```
    dependencies {
       runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'
    }
```

and I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar file added to the build path and the /lib/ folder .

On the remote DB, by connecting to it through HeidiSQL client on my machine, I have run the following query based on my research on the same topic of discussion.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <DB_Name>.* TO <username>@'%' IDENTIFIED BY <password>;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I ping to the remote server from the command prompt, that too works fine.

```
ping <Remote Server IP>

Pinging <Remote Server IP> with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from <Remote Server IP>: bytes=32 time=261ms TTL=61
Reply from <Remote Server IP>: bytes=32 time=261ms TTL=61
Reply from <Remote Server IP>: bytes=32 time=257ms TTL=61
Reply from <Remote Server IP>: bytes=32 time=257ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for <Remote Server IP>:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 257ms, Maximum = 261ms, Average = 259ms
```

Now, when I run the application using GGTS Run As -> Grails Command (run-app) I get the following error:

```
| Error 2016-12-13 18:36:05,400 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  409 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1118 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    343 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2308 | connectOneTryOnly in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2122 | createNewIO in     ''
|    774 | <init>    in     ''
|     49 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    409 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    375 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    289 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    339 | doConnect in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
|    200 | connectToAddress in     ''
|    182 | connect   in     ''
|    172 | connect . in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
|    392 | connect   in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    579 | connect . in java.net.Socket
|    528 | connect   in     ''
|    425 | <init> .  in     ''
|    241 | <init>    in     ''
|    256 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    292 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2308 | connectOneTryOnly in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2122 | createNewIO in     ''
|    774 | <init> .  in     ''
|     49 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    409 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    375 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    289 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I have tried all the available solutions from stack-overflow and other websites.
Till now I've been following the solutions available on

1. http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#dataSource
2. [Access MySQL server from Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012308/access-mysql-server-from-grails)

and a few other links which I am not able to post here due to less reputation on stack-overflow.

I have done exactly the same that has been asked to be done on all of the solutions available in the above mentioned links. Still I am having the same error. I am not sure what I am missing out on. Not even sure if this is caused due to the VPN connection or something.
Please help me.

Comment: Here are the other links that I had been refferring to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435187/grails-run-app-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872591/connecting-to-a-grails-app-database
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/
https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/116/topics/3883
http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/grails-hosting-demistified-with-simple-database-application

Comment: Focus on the error "org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure". It's not really a Grails issue (other than possible mis-configuration of the dataSource). In a nutshell, there's a problem connecting to MySQL; which of course can be caused by a number of issues. If you can connect to the database and execute queries from HeidiSQL, then the issue is with the dataSource configuration. Otherwise, the issue is with the connection itself.

Comment: Ok so the issue is with DataSource configuration. But I've tried all that I could from all the available solutions online. Still the issue persists.

Comment: I also read that the issue may be due to the presence of an antivirus with firewall turned On. I have turned off the firewall in Macafee anti virus installed on my computer and still the issue persists.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I did a further research and checked the MySQL conf file my.cnf in ./etc/mysql/ . In the file under [mysqld] section bind-address is set to 127.0.0.1. is this an issue? Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on localhost for all mysql ubuntu installations. can you suggest what else can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved finally.

I checked the MySQL conf file my.cnf in the server location ./etc/mysql/ . In the file my.cnf, under [mysqld] section, bind-address is set to 127.0.0.1. Instead of skip-networking being set to True, the default is now to listen only on localhost for all mysql ubuntu installations in order to avoid other servers connecting to mySQL.

Hence I commented out the line, setting bind-address=127.0.0.1 in the file my.cnf in ./etc/mysql/ folder and restarted the mysql and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Sometime when we have layer e.g docker, firewell, or proxy then these type of error comes which are harder to troubleshoot. I have faced similary type of error. I just solved this issue by bind the server with '0.0.0.0' instead of 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. by using this. etc/host will expose the server binding to all interfaces. and then i checked that the IP for localhost by using 'ifconfig' command. then used that IP to my internal archtecture docker application. thats works fine.